# Data NULL with hook processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations()

Tags: php, typo3, hook

I'm a new user of typo3 and I'm using the "processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations" to send a notification to users when I create alerts messages with my extension.

```
        $storagePid = $hookObjectsArr->getPID($table, $id);
        $pageTsConfig = BackendUtility::getPagesTSconfig($storagePid);
        $this->settings = $pageTsConfig['tx_alerte.'];
        if ($table === 'tx_Myappalerte_domain_model_alerte' && ($this->settings['enabled'] === '1')) {
<mycode>
}
```

My issue is when I create a new alert, I have an error message because all my variables ($storagePid, $pageTsConfig, $this->settings) are NULL, I checked it with var_dump, but when I'm updating an existing alert, theses variables aren't NULL.
I know the ID is obviously NULL because the alert isn't created

Is there a way to make what I want to do work?

thanks you

Comment: See the comment above [processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations] (https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/5747c5b2634862df29d074a580962a924928270e/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php#L774 ) 

Note: When using the hook after INSERT operations, you will only get the temporary NEW... id passed to your hook as $id,
     * but you can easily translate it to the real uid of the inserted record using the **$this->substNEWwithIDs** array.

Comment: I tried to add if (GeneralUtility::isFirstPartOfStr($id, 'new')){$id = $pObj->substNEWwithIDs[$id];} I have my new id , but $storagePid is still FALSE

Comment: You have the 5th parameter `$fieldArray` available. `$fieldArray['pid']` is the pid.  

`if (str_contains($id, 'NEW')) {    // Replace NEW...-ID with real uid:
    $id = $this->substNEWwithIDs[$id] ?? '';`